# Using Laravel Eloquent's with() function along with inner join

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent, eager-loading

I encountered a problem when trying to use `with()` function along with join:

```
$query = Model::query()->with([
  'relationOne',
  'relationTwo',
  ...
]);

$query->join(DB::raw("(
  select *
  from <models_table>
  where <some_condition>
) as new_model"), 'new_model.id', '=', '<models_table>.id');

$query->paginate($rpp);
```

After `paginate($rpp)` call I received all items with appropriate relations appended, but without joined table (aka `new_model`). Is there a way to retrieve `new_model` along with relations ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? why use a join instead of a relation and a query builder ?

Comment: @N69S Because the table I'm trying to join is a 'raw' table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to add `select` statement to emphasize the tables you want to get?

```
$query->join(DB::raw("(
  select *
  from <models_table>
  where <some_condition>
) as new_model"), 'new_model.id', '=', '<models_table>.id')
->select(['<models_table>.*', 'new_model.*']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code hope it will help you.

```
$query = Model::query()->with([
  'relationOne',
  'relationTwo',
  ...
])

$query = $query->join(DB::raw("(
  select *
  from <models_table>
  where <some_condition>
) as new_model"), 'new_model.id', '=', '<models_table>.id')

$query = $query->paginate($rpp);
```

Comment: Try add `->select('models.*', 'new_model.id as new_model_id', 'new_model.title as new_model_title' ...)`, think join work in sql, and return correct data, but laravel merge same attrubute names

Comment: Can you `dump($query->toSql())` before paginate?